# Creating a new column in ddplyr with sums by multiple groupings

Tags: r, dplyr, formatting, summarize

I have a data frame (x) in ddplyr that looks like this:

```
Location   Type   Method   Observations
Outside    Small  A        1
Outside    Large  A        5
Inside     Small  A        20
Inside     Large  A        17
Outside    Small  B        24
Outside    Large  B        0
Inside     Small  B        0
Inside     Large  B        12 
Outside    Small  C        6
Outside    Large  C        0
Inside     Small  C        1
Inside     Large  C        85
```

What I’m trying to do is make a new data frame (y) that lists the total observations by location and method. So something like this:

```
Location    Method    Total_Observations
Outside     A         6
Inside      A         37
Outside     B         24
Inside      B         12
Outside     C         6
Inside      C         86
```

Basically, I need to collapse Type so that all of those observation values (for each location and method) are added together and placed in one column.

So far, what I have is this:

```
y <- x %>%
  group_by(Location,Method) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  summarise(Total_Observations = sum(Observations))
```

The problem is that this option (and all others I’ve tried) gives me a sum of the number of rows instead of adding up the numbers within them. Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: "this option (and all others I’ve tried) gives me a sum of the number of rows instead of adding up the numbers within them". Your output table and code tells me otherwise. Are you sure this is not what you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your desired outcome, it looks like your script already does what you want it to. Adding up all the observations for each location and method. (e.g for *Outside* and *A*, there are 1 and 5 observations, you want the *Total_Observations* to be  6) Dplyr by default orders items by the first column. To get the outcome to look exactly like the outcome as you have above, I simply added an "arrange" statement.

```
library(dplyr)
y <- x %>%
group_by(Location,Method) %>%
replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
summarise(Total_Observations = sum(Observations)) %>%
arrange(Method, desc(Location))
```